# XMonad won't spawn anything with mod4Mask

Tags: linux, haskell, fedora, xmonad, xfce

I have seen a few somewhat similar problems on the Arch forums, but I have not been able to find a solution for this.

So I am running XMonad 0.1 in XFCE4 on Fedora 17 x64, and I have xmonad-contrib installed as well. Here is my xmonad.hs file:

```
import System.Posix.Env (getEnv)
import Data.Maybe (maybe)
import Control.Monad
import XMonad.Hooks.SetWMName
import qualified XMonad.StackSet as W
import XMonad.Util.EZConfig

import XMonad
import XMonad.Config.Desktop
import XMonad.Config.Gnome
import XMonad.Config.Kde
import XMonad.Config.Xfce

main = do
     session <- getEnv "DESKTOP_SESSION"
     xmonad  $ xfceConfig     --(maybe desktopConfig desktop session)        
        {
        modMask = mod4Mask
        , terminal = "gnome-terminal"
        , logHook = takeTopFocus >> setWMName "LG3D"
        }
        `additionalKeys` [ ((mod4Mask, xK_p), spawn "dmenu_run")
                           ,((mod4Mask, xK_v), spawn "gvim")
            ]


-----------------------------------------
------------Custom Keys------------------
-----------------------------------------


-----------------------------------------
------------Other horrible stuff---------
-----------------------------------------

desktop "gnome" = gnomeConfig
desktop "kde" = kde4Config
desktop "xfce" = xfceConfig
desktop "xmonad-gnome" = gnomeConfig
desktop _ = desktopConfig

atom_WM_TAKE_FOCUS ::
  X Atom
atom_WM_TAKE_FOCUS =
  getAtom "WM_TAKE_FOCUS"

takeFocusX ::
  Window
  -> X ()
takeFocusX w =
  withWindowSet . const $ do
    dpy       <- asks display
    wmtakef   <- atom_WM_TAKE_FOCUS
    wmprot    <- atom_WM_PROTOCOLS
    protocols <- io $ getWMProtocols dpy w
    when (wmtakef `elem` protocols) $
      io . allocaXEvent $ \ev -> do
          setEventType ev clientMessage
          setClientMessageEvent ev w wmprot 32 wmtakef currentTime
          sendEvent dpy w False noEventMask ev

takeTopFocus ::
  X ()
takeTopFocus =
  withWindowSet $ maybe (setFocusX =<< asks theRoot) takeFocusX . W.peek
```

You will notice in the `additionalKeys` part, I have 2 bindings. Both are using `mod4Mask`, which is also my default mod key. The second binding, for gvim, works perfectly. The problem is that the first binding, for dmenu, simply does nothing. What's strange is that if I change `mod4Mask` (for dmenu) to `mod1Mask` then it works. Also, dmenu works fine if I run it from a terminal.

EDIT: mod4Mask and P doesn't seem to spawn / do anything.

Any ideas? This config seems fine to me, I have no idea why it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what's wrong, but I have a few suggestions for debugging it.

1. I've had situations where I thought I was running my current custom xmonad.hs, but I was really running a previous version or the default. Rule this out by making some other change to your xmonad.hs, and verifying that it works.
2. Try mapping mod4Mask p to something else, and see if that works.
3. Using xev, press mod4Mask + p, and verify that it indeed generates the events you're expecting. Compare with mod4Mask + v, and see if there's any difference apart from the change from p to v.
4. Make sure you don't have NumLock or Fn or something like that active! (NumLock would change your p to a number, I think.)

What kind of keyboard are you using? US? UK? Something else?

Comment: 1. I think I am using the default xconfig, I haven't needed to change it.

2. mod4Mask p doesn't launch anything

3. xev seems fine, it shows Super_L (mod4Mask) and a keycode changes (which is obviously p or v)

4. NumLock makes no difference, I don't have FN lock

and I am using a US keyboard (HP KU-0316)

Comment: I still haven't figured out the problem; I just changed the key-combo to mod4Mask and d

Comment: I don't have much expertise in this area, but the only options I can think of are that something else is trapping the mod4mask p event, or that there is something unusual about your keyboard map. You might try running `xmodmap -pke`. In the output from that command, see if there's anything unusual in any of the mappings for the p key (compare with the v key).

Are you using xmonad alone, or in conjunction with something like Gnome?

Comment: I also think that something is catching this key combo. I am using xfce here, but I looked in keyboard shortcuts and there was nothing unusual. I'll try your suggestion and post back

Comment: Hmm I installed MATE to try it out and it doesn't have the same problem - mod4Mask P works fine

Comment: By any chance, if you open a terminal and type `xmonad --restart`, does it solve the problem? If so, your problem may be related to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965699/xmonad-dmenu-not-launching-spawning-on-startup

Comment: Indeed NumLock was my problem!  But -- WTF? -- why?  Why should NumLock turn my mon4Mask+p into a number?

Comment: Because most laptops don't have a numeric keypad, the NumLock key is configured to turn part of the regular keyboard into a numeric keypad.

Answer (score 1):

XFCE binds Mod4-p to something in this file

```
~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml
```

By searching for "Super" in that file I find two lines with < Super>-p. One seems to be "empty" and the other executes "xfce4-display-settings --minimal" for setting up an external display output.

I changed both occurrences in that file to use o instead of p and then logged out of XFCE and back in. Now Mod4-p works in XMonad!