# XMonad: dmenu not launching/spawning on startup

Tags: linux, haskell, ubuntu-12.04, xmonad

New to XMonad and loving it so far. I have a fairly vanilla / regular XMonad setup and am having problems with **dmenu**. When I login and hit `mod+p` nothing happens. If I then open a terminal and hit `xmonad --restart` then `mod+p`, `dmenu` will be working.

There must be something wrong with my `xmonad.hs`? I tried a no-customization setup of XMonad and things were working normally (i.e. `dmenu` was working after login).

My questions:

1. Is there something wrong with my `xmonad.hs`?
2. Why won't `dmenu` work unless I `xmonad --restart` ?
3. Could something fail in `xmonad.start` that would prevent dmenu from loading properly when starting xmonad?

Here are my files (borrowed from [overthink](https://github.com/overthink/dotfiles)). :

**xmonad.hs**

```
import System.IO
import XMonad
import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
import XMonad.Hooks.SetWMName
import XMonad.Util.EZConfig(additionalKeys)
import XMonad.Util.Run(spawnPipe)
import XMonad.Hooks.ICCCMFocus

myWorkspaces = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"] 

myManageHook = composeAll
  [ className =? "Gimp" --> doFloat
  , className =? "Vncviewer" --> doFloat
  ]

main = do
  xmproc <- spawnPipe "/usr/bin/xmobar /home/aaron/.xmobarrc"
  xmonad $ defaultConfig { terminal = "urxvt" }
      { manageHook = manageDocks <+> manageHook defaultConfig
      , startupHook = takeTopFocus >> setWMName "LG3D" -- fix for Java apps
      , layoutHook = avoidStruts  $  layoutHook defaultConfig
      , logHook = dynamicLogWithPP xmobarPP
                      { ppOutput = hPutStrLn xmproc
                      , ppTitle = xmobarColor "green" "" . shorten 50
                      }
      , modMask = mod4Mask     -- Rebind Mod to the Windows key
      , workspaces = myWorkspaces
      } `additionalKeys`
      [ ((mod4Mask .|. shiftMask, xK_l), spawn "gnome-screensaver-command --lock") ]
```

**xmonad.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Xmonad-****
Comment=Ligthweight, pretentious tiling window manager
Exec=xmonad.start
Icon=xmonad.png
Type=XSession
```

**xmonad.start**

```
#!/bin/bash

xrdb -merge .Xresources

trayer --edge top --align right --SetDockType true --SetPartialStrut true --expand true --widthtype percent --width 10 --heighttype pixel --height 20 --transparent true --alpha 0 --tint 0x333333 &

# settings daemon is a prereq for some other gnome apps
gnome-settings-daemon &

# Network monitor (connections, vpns) applet in tray
if [ -x /usr/bin/nm-applet ] ; then
    nm-applet --sm-disable &
fi

# volume indicator in tray
if [ -x /usr/bin/gnome-sound-applet ] ; then
  gnome-sound-applet &
fi

eval $(gnome-keyring-daemon --start)
export GNOME_KEYRING_SOCKET
export GNOME_KEYRING_PID

#exec xmonad
dbus-launch --exit-with-session xmonad
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It doesn't sound to me like there's a problem with your xmonad.hs file. Did you install Xmonad using cabal, or using your system's package manager? Your symptoms are similar to what happened to me a while back when I had unintentionally installed xmonad both ways, so I had two xmonad executables.

Comment: I installed xmonad via `apt-get` (I'm running ubuntu). Funny enough, on my work machine I did the same thing (installed twice).

Answer (score 1):

I have a vague feeling that when you first launch xmonad, it uses one executable+configuration, and then when you recompile, it finds the "right" one. In xmonad.desktop, try changing the `Exec=` line to include a full path to your xmonad.start.

```
Exec=/full/path/to/xmonad.start
```

Or you might try changing the last line in xmonad.start to include the full path to your xmonad executable.

```
dbus-launch --exit-with-session /full/path/to/xmonad
```

Another thing to try is changing the last two lines to:

```
exec xmonad
#dbus-launch --exit-with-session xmonad
```

If any of these options change the behaviour you're seeing, that might give us a clue.

---

EDIT: Let's try a different way of launching it, to see if we can learn anything. Don't start any window manager, log into a plain terminal instead. Type the command `xinit -- xmonad` or `xinit -- /full/path/to/xmonad`.

Alternatively, create the file `.xinitrc` with one line in it:

```
xmonad
```

Then type the command `startx`.

I also found this on the Xmonad FAQ, which may help:

> 2.6 not found errors or changes to xmonad.hs won't take effect
>
> Ensure that ghc, and the xmonad executable are both in the environment
>   PATH from which you start X. Alternatively symlink them to locations
>   already in the PATH. ghc-pkg list should show ghc, xmonad, X11, etc.
>   without brackets, e.g. {xmonad} is bad. ghc-pkg check will tell you if
>   you have inconsistent dependencies or other registration problems.
>
> The mod-q action calls the xmonad binary to recompile itself, so if
>   your display manager is starting it with /path/to/xmonad you'll also
>   have to edit your xmonad.hs mod-q binding to use the full path and
>   restart X (or in newer versions use 'xmonad --restart') to restart
>   xmonad with the new mod-q full path binding.

Comment: I added some other things to try. We're reaching the limit of my knowledge in this area, so if none of that helps, and no one else here provides an answer, you might check the Xmonad mailing list or IRC channel (info for both is on http://xmonad.org/community.html). And if you do get an answer elsewhere, you can come back here to add the answer yourself, and accept it as the solution. My instinct tells me that it is some sort of path problem, where something isn't on the path when Xmonad is first launched, but when you restart, it is on the path.

Comment: FWIW, I'm the author of the config shown in the question above.  This had been working well for me in Ubuntu 12.04 until a recent `apt-get dist-upgrade`.  I was sloppy and didn't pay attention, so I  don't know what was upgraded, but things are now broken for me in the way @weirdcanada describes.  Still trying to hunt down what is really going on.

Comment: More updates: I installed XMonad on my work machine (Ubuntu 12) using `apt-get` with no `xmonad.hs` configuration whatsoever and `dmenu` works fine. Strange.

Comment: Are you using `gdm`? When you log in, if you're using a GUI, then I'm guessing that it's `gdm`, or perhaps `xdm` or `wdm`.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

The fix that seems to have solved the problem is changing:

```
exec xmonad
```

To:

```
touch ~/.xmonad/xmonad.hs
exec xmonad
```

in

```
/usr/local/bin/xmonad.start (or .xinitrc/.xsession if xmonad is started using startx)
```

---

OLD:

How about changing:

```
} `additionalKeys`
 [ ((mod4Mask .|. shiftMask, xK_l), spawn "gnome-screensaver-command --lock") ]
```

To:

```
} `additionalKeys`
  [ ((mod4Mask .|. shiftMask, xK_l), spawn "gnome-screensaver-command --lock") 
  , ((mod4Mask, xK_p), spawn "dmenu_run -b -nb black") ]
```

I had the same issue as you and it was because I had used something like:

```
((mod4Mask, xK_p), spawn "exe=`dmenu_path | dmenu` && eval \"exec $exe\"")
```

which, for some reason, only works properly after a "xmonad --restart". Changing the binding to simply "dmenu-run" fixed the problem. In your case, though, it looks like you're missing the binding at all.